# Ambiguous call that doesn't appear to be ambiguous

Tags: c++, .net-core, c++-cli

Working in C++/CLI using dotnetcore 3.1.  Maybe I've just been staring at this too long but I'm just not seeing it.  Here is a constructor for one of my classes...

```
FooReader::FooReader(Stream^ stream) : FooReader()
{
   _streamReader = gcnew StreamReader(stream);
   _ownStreamReader = true;
}
```

When compiling I get the following...

> ambiguous call to overloaded function
> could be 'System::IO::StreamReader::StreamReader(System::IO::Stream ^,System::Text::Encoding ^,bool,int,bool)'
> or 'System::IO::StreamReader::StreamReader(System::IO::Stream ^)
> while trying to match the argument list '(System::IO::Stream ^)'

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1) there are only two constructors for StreamReader that take one argument... one takes a `String^` and the other takes a `Stream^`.  Looks to me like I have an exact match to one of the signatures... where is the ambiguity?  I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: Works fine as posted.  But can happen when you have *two* reference assemblies that declare System::IO::Stream.

Comment: @HansPassant - I can't prove it, as I've deleted/recreated the project but I think you're right.  I was converting it from .Net to Core 3.1 so maybe some pieces of the old references didn't get removed cleanly.  Seems like the most likely suspect.  If you want to convert your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Have the same problem after updating my projects from .NET Framework to .NET 5.0. As a test I created a new project and added in my source files and required references and the problem still exists. The problem assembly is c++/cli while my reference assemblies are c# (don't know if that makes a difference).

Comment: @HansPassant - If you want to convert your comment to an answer I'll accept it.  Your rep # is a little anemic, after all ;) - All kidding aside, thanks for the nudge in the right direction